# Is there a way to have a scrollbar automatically move down to the most recent additions to a div through adding javascript textnodes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div block that tells the user what keys they just pressed. I'm using overflow-y set to auto and when the div block is full the scroll bar does start working, except the most recent editions are unreadable without scrolling. Is there a way to have the scrollbar move automatically when a new line is made?

Comment: Why do you need it to be automatic? Can't you just call `scrollingElement.scrollTo(scrollingElement.scrollHeight);` after you did append the new content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the position of the text

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
var vertical_pos = testDiv.offsetHeight; // Choose if scroll up or down.
var horizotal_pos = testDiv.offsetWidth; // Choose if left right scrolling is needed
```

Scroll to the position

```
window.scrollTo(horizotal_pos, vertical_pos); // Default = 0
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Here, "test" is the id of first of the latest posts. you can also query by class, name or other attributes